# DataTables Server-side processing con Ajax

Tags: ajax, datatables

he seguido este pequeño ejemplo de DataTables al pie de la letra:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Pero tengo problemas con la obtención de los datos en JSON y me sale un alert con el siguiente error:

> DataTables warning: table id=tablaAjax - Invalid JSON response. For
>   more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

Mi código es el siguiente:

**tabla.php**

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tablaAjax" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>idUsuario</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>idUsuario</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tablaAjax').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "getdata.php"
        } );
    } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**getdata.php**

```
<?php
// DB table to use
$table = 'usuario';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'idUsuario';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'idUsuario', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'nombre',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'apellido',   'dt' => 2 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'user',
    'pass' => 'pass',
    'db'   => 'db',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);
?>
```

He consultado la página que me da el error, he comprobado que no hay respuesta del fichero **getdata.php**, solo que el nombre del fichero cambia, debido al método GET:
http://localhost/tabla/getdata.php?draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=idUsuario&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5...

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Podrías enseñar el formato json que recibes

Comment: No obtengo resultado de respuesta, me sale ""This request has no response data available". La única respuesta es el resultado que he mostrado de la url o con el método POST que es el mismo que la url.